# El operador '<' está reservado para uso futuro

Tags: mysql

Al querer importar el archivo esquema.sql por consola en el Visual Studio Code:
C:\xampp\htdocs\okventa> mysql -u root -p okventa_by_parzibyte < esquema.sql (esta es la ruta q le indico)
me salta el siguiente error:

En línea: 1 Carácter: 39

- mysql -u root -p okventa_by_parzibyte < esquema.sql

El operador '<' está reservado para uso futuro.

- CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [],ParentContainsErrorRecordException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported

Hay otra manera de importar el archivo .sql para no usar el operador < ?
Muchas gracias

Comment: prueba con 'mysql -u root -p okventa_by_parzibyte source esquema.sql'

Comment: Hola Micky, bienvenido, Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Después de `-p` no va espacio.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por tomarse el tiempo de responder, probé de la manera que me indican en sus comentarios y no funcionó, investigando un poco mas, me di cuenta de que el visual s. code estaba funcionando con el Powershell, solo tuve que Cambiar al CMD. La manera de hacerlo es: presionar F1 dentro del editor y escribir  -Terminal: "Seleccionar perfil predeterminado", y ahí elegimos 'Command prompt' y listo, mi problema se solucionó, ahora el cmd si lo reconoce al '<' como operador, todo funciona ok. Nuevamente Gracias a Todos